# How to perform canonicalization in a subdomain?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, subdomain, canonical-link

I am stuck with canonicalization because with example.com it's working fine but when running checker on subdomain.example.com it's throwing errors like

> URL Canonicalization Test http://subdomain.example.com/new/
> http://subdomain.example.com/new and
> http://www.subdomain.example.com/new should resolve to the same URL,
> but currently do not.

I am using seositecheckup tool to measure SEO faults. However, that's doesn't matter so much just as a note to keep.

Now it's suggesting to put this into .htaccess but the error still occurs

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Now my PHP code is this for canonical tag  (It has worked well with example.com

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php $link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? 
                                      "https" : "http") . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .  
                                      $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                                      echo $link; ?>" />
```

So how could I remove the error and fix the canonical link for all pages suggestion required?
I highly thank you so much for reading the question and would like to get an appropriate answer.

Comment: Unless you have a specific use-case for non-secure, I would always enforce `HTTPS` for URLs. I get that there's dev-reasons, but those are solvable. Should `www.sub.example.com` have a canonical to `sub.example.com`? I'd say no, but I wouldn't argue the point too far. Should `example.com/page` have a canonical to `example.com/page/`? Once again, arguable.

Comment: Specifying the canonical purely based on information taken from the request, makes rather little sense to begin with. (At least nt unless you have fixed all the other versions via redirects first.)